# Different font sizes on pc and mobile in bootstrap

Tags: html, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a very simple page here:
http://rasadata.gigfa.com/bootstrap/Home.html

When I open it in my pc browser everything is normal but when I open it in my LG G3 phone text size is very small that is impossible to read.

Why? I want to have a sensible text size on both devices.

What is wrong?

Here is the simple html:

```
<div class="container">

 <div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-4">
  <p>A simple text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
  <p>A simple text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
  <p>A simple text</p>
  </div>

 </div>

</div>
```

Text size on pc is normal but in mobile is very very small.
How can I have the same text size on both devices?

Comment: Do you have any custom `CSS` on the site that could be causing this issue?

Comment: I have but it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing this mobile-first meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: I have seen the live site and it was missing, when I added it using browser editor, it worked.

Comment: Put this is tag inside <head>.

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect the html of your work, you'll see that in bootstrap css, font set into `10px` (`font-size:10px;`) even though your body font size is `14px`;

Change it into 14px as well as your body font size. Otherwise, create new custom stylesheet to write it.

Take a look at screenshot of your page;

[image: ss]

font size in your mobile:
[image: ss2]

Comment: The problem was because I had forgotten to add the meta tag. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I was also not accurate seeing your script :D. that viewport is a must in bootstrap

Comment: Sometimes you forget the simplest things and they cause even greater mess ups :D